# NULLS in WHERE statements - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I have a conditional statement in my `WHERE` statement, are `NULL`s automatically not included?

For example, in a query with a `GROUP BY` statement that has the line `FROM @data WHERE Trade_Amt > 0 AND Execution_Code != 'EXPIRATION'`, `Execution_Code` values that are `null` will not be included in the summation.

If I include `OR Execution_Code IS NULL` then I get more records than expected.

The only work around that I have found is changing the `null` values to a specified character.  Is this my only option or am I missing something?

An example:

Table `@data`

```
Trade_Amt       Execution_Code   Trade_Px
-----------------------------------------
4                  XVD             5
-4                 NULL            5
4                  NULL            5
5                  EXPIRATION      5
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Trade_Amt) AS [Trade_Amt],
    dbo.ConcatStr(DISTINCT Execution_Code , ',', 'ASC') AS [Execution_Code],
    Trade_Px
    --above line concatenates execution code strings together during summation  
FROM 
    @data 
WHERE 
    Trade_Amt > 0 AND Execution_Code != 'EXPIRATION'
GROUP BY
    Trade_Px
```

Expected output:

```
Trade_Amt       Execution_Code     Trade_Px
--------------------------------------------
   8                 XVD              5
```

What I actually get:

```
Trade_Amt       Execution_Code     Trade_Px
--------------------------------------------
   4                 XVD              5
```

Comment: Why would the answer be _0_? since the where clause is only including `trade_amt > 0`?

Comment: Also, include the query with `is null` that isn't working for you.

Comment: Its a summation on Trade_Amt.

Comment: But only summing values greater than zero, so the -4 doesn't get summed with the 4 to make zero.

Comment: I thought summation sums up numbers regardless of sign.

Comment: Only those values that are included. You where clause `WHERE 
    Trade_Amt > 0`  that will exclude rows where the trade amount is not greater than zero. `Where` happens (logically) before `group by`.

Comment: Sorry about that...fixed the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `()` to specify that you only want the execution codes that aren't equal to expiration and are null

```
WHERE Trade_Amt > 0 AND (Execution_Code != 'EXPIRATION' OR Execution_Code IS NULL)
```

If you don't have the `()`, you won't get the results you're expecting.

Comment: I tried that and I got more records than expected.  Keep in mind the example above is just a snippet of a much larger dataset

Comment: Did you use the parentheses?

Comment: Nice, that worked.  I didn't include parenthesis before.  Thank you!!  But I still don't understand why I must include null.

Comment: @Mureinik gave a pretty good explanation of why you must include `null`. `Null` is a special value and can only be checked using `is null` or `is not null`

Answer (score 0):

NULL is a different sort of value.  It cannot be tested as greater than or less than.  Because it is neither.  It is NULL.
So the only way to test if a value is NULL is:

```
Select thisvalue from thistable where value is NULL
```

or

```
Select thisvalue from thistable where value is not NULL
```

So you need to separate these sorts of things in cases where the value could indeed be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not a value - it is the lack thereof. For any operator that handles values (such as `=`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `like`, etc.), it returns an "unknown" result. Since "unknown" is not "true", such conditions will exclude `null` values, unless you handle them explicitly using the `is` operator:

```
SELECT   SUM(Trade_Amt),
         dbo.ConcatStr(DISTINCT Execution_Code , ',', 'ASC') AS [Execution_Code],
         Trade_Px
FROM     @data 
WHERE    (Trade_Amt IS NULL OR Trade_Amt > 0) AND 
         (Execution_Code IS NULL OR Execution_Code != 'EXPIRATION')
GROUP BY Trade_Px
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can use parentheses to make sure `is null` is part of your `execution_criteria`.  You can also use the `ISNULL` function, like so:

```
WHERE Trade_Amt > 0 AND ISNULL(Execution_Code, 'X') != 'EXPIRATION'
```

Where `'X'` can be anything you want, as long as it isn't 'Expiration.'  In the case that your `Execution_Code` is `NULL`, it will instead check to see  that 'X' is not equal to 'Expiration,' which of course it won't be.